# Can not Login with credentials of any other user than the one created at first place Mongodb and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, authentication, postman

I am facing this issue in react that when I create user other than the first one the users gets created in the mongodb but when I try to login with the credentials of any other users I get this internal node error 464 in terminal with the message of wrong password in postman and the API crashes also if the password for the first registered user is wrong the API crashes in same manner. Also the login request doesn't verify the username it only cares about the password. I have no idea what is causing this issue. I checked my code but it seems fine to me. Can someone please assist who may have faced and solved this problem? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

My code for auth is:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
      req.body.password,
      process.env.PASS_SEC
    ).toString(),
  });

  try {
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//LOGIN

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne(
            {
                userName: req.body.user_name
            }
        );

        !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong User Name");

        const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
            user.password,
            process.env.PASS_SEC
        );


        const originalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

        const inputPassword = req.body.password;
        
        originalPassword != inputPassword && 
            res.status(401).json("Wrong Password");

        const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        {
            id: user._id,
            isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
        },
        process.env.JWT_SEC,
            {expiresIn:"3d"}
        );
  
        const { password, ...others } = user._doc;  
        res.status(200).json({...others, accessToken});

    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }

});

module.exports = router;
```

And the error that I get in the terminal is

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\Shop Api Test\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\Shop Api Test\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\Shop Api Test\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at D:\Shop Api Test\routes\auth.js:63:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 0):

the error

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

usually happens when you send response again while you already sent response back to client.
so i think when user send wrong pass you send `res.status(401).json("Wrong Password");` and since you're not returning, the function still runs and execute codes after that so the second `res.status().json()` will call and cause the error

change your code like this and always retrun if you don't wanna do anything after sending response back

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({
      userName: req.body.user_name
    });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json("Wrong User Name");
    }

    const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      user.password,
      process.env.PASS_SEC
    );

    const originalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    const inputPassword = req.body.password;

    if (originalPassword != inputPassword) {
        return res.status(401).json("Wrong Password");
    }
      
    const accessToken = jwt.sign({
        id: user._id,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SEC, {
        expiresIn: "3d"
      }
    );

    const { password, others } = user._doc;
    return res.status(200).json({ ...others, accessToken });

  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help this solution did resolve the API crash problem. But still I can not login with the credentials of other users than the one created at first place still getting wrong password for all other users. That's the error I get in console if I use this API with the frontend ```POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login 401 (Unauthorized)```

Comment: i don't see any error with your password checking, try to decrypt your passwords in database manually to see what you get

Comment: also check `originalPassword` in your code